# Is it possible to have auto suggest running for this typescript code?

Tags: typescript

for the following code, I copied some types and pasted them in typescript.
I defined an interface called **user** which contains username/password as shown below in the code snippet

the issue I'm currently having is autosuggesting the parameters I defined for the **const rules**.

please find the code below with the defined types/interfaces

```
type ValidatorFn <T = any, K = any, S = any> = (value: T, siblingState: K, vm: S) => boolean;

interface ValidationRuleWithoutParams <T = any> {
  $validator: ValidatorFn<T>
  $message?: string  | (() => string)
}

interface ValidationRuleWithParams<P extends object = object, T = any> {
  $validator: ValidatorFn<T>
  $message: (input: { $params: P }) => string
  $params: P
}

type ValidationRule <T = any> = ValidationRuleWithParams<any, T> | ValidationRuleWithoutParams<T> | ValidatorFn<T>;

type ValidationRuleCollection <T = any> = Record<string, ValidationRule<T>>;

type ValidationArgs<T = unknown> = {
  [key in keyof T]: ValidationArgs<T[key]> | ValidationRuleCollection<T[key]> | ValidationRule<T[key]>
}

interface user{
    username: string;
    password: string
}


const rules = <ValidationArgs<user>>{
    username:{
        shouldAutoSuggest: ()=>false
    },
    password: {
        shouldAutoSuggest: ()=>false
    }
};
```

when I reference `rules.username.shouldAutoSuggest`, it doesn't recognize (shouldAutoSuggest) function.
how to make it possible to recognize.
i'm using vscode

Comment: interface user has username and password set as strings(?)

Comment: @Nick yes as shown above in the code, the interface contains 2 properties, username and password, both as strings

Comment: Why do you need to specify the type of `rules` at all?  If you just let the compiler infer the type of `rules`, you can still use it anywhere a `ValidationArgs<User>` is required, like [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WY4KEm) shows.  Does that example meet your needs? If not, please [edit] the code to show a use case where it fails.  (Also, the naming convention for non-primitive types is UpperPascalCase, so you should probably write `User` instead of `user`)

Comment: @jcalz for the convention type, you are correct. I just missed it. the rules i would like to auto suggest inside them too, and I need to specify the type so that I can write the rules inside of it.

Comment: You missed it, but you can fix it by [edit]ing the question.  Where, specifically, do you want to see autosuggesting happening?  You say "inside them", but what and where?  You can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NByYxw) to ask the compiler to infer a more specific type than `ValidationArgs<User>`, and it will autosuggest the key names.  Does that work for you?  Or what am I missing?